# Find ordered pair (α,β)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

Let matrix A = $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    0 & 5 & 4 \\
    0 & 3 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
and $A^3$ - $8A^2$ + αA + βI = O

where I =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}

Then the ordered pair (α,β) is:

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the characteristic polynomial $p$ of $A$. $p$ has degree $3$ and, by Cayley-Hamilton:

$$p(A)=0.$$

Comment: Thank you, I never heard of Cayley-Hamilton theorem before, I learned it now and I was able to solve the problem.